# How do I save a video with an alpha channel in GStreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, alpha, avi, alpha-transparency

I have a collection of RGBA png files, and have verified the presence of an alpha layer on each file:

`gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="pics/%d.png" ! decodebin ! videorate ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRA,framerate=60/1 ! videomixer background=checker ! videoconvert ! ximagesink`

I want to take these files and make them into a video file (in any format that GStreamer will readily handle with a simple `decodebin`).  What would be a good set of encoders, containers, and elements to use for this?

I've tried `avimux` but no alpha data was saved.  I also tried  `avenc_huffyuv`, and that would decode fine as raw data using `avenc_huffyuv`, but `decodebin` could not detect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing like a good night's sleep to solve an issue..

Apparently the huffyuv encoder and avi muxer work nicely together to preserve tranpsarency:

`gst-launch-1.0 multifilesrc location="pics/%d.png" ! decodebin ! videorate ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRA,framerate=60/1 ! avenc_huffyuv ! avimux ! filesink location=/tmp/test.avi`